# How to use a dictionary to save a directed graph in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

Given a set of edges of a graph as follows:

```
/* Edges */
("C", "E", 2)
("C", "D", 3)
("E", "D", 1)
("E", "G", 3)
("E", "F", 2)
("D", "F", 4)
("G", "H", 2)
("F", "G", 2)
("F", "H", 1)
```

How can I write the code to save them in a dictionary as follows (C to H, in python):

```
{"C": {"E": 2, "D": 3}, "E": {"D": 1, "G": 3, "F": 2}, "D": {"F": 4}, "G": {"H": 2}, "F": {"G": 2, "H": 1}, "H": {}}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This link may help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-graph-using-dictionary-python/

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the keys and value with `re` and use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import re, collections
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
_, *data = [re.findall('(?<=")\w+(?=")', i) for i in content.split('\n')]
for a, b, c in data:
  d[a][b] = int(c)

d = {**d, **{i[1]:{} for i in data if not any(c[0] == i[1] for c in data)}}
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'C': {'E': 2, 'D': 3}, 'E': {'D': 1, 'G': 3, 'F': 2}, 'D': {'F': 4}, 'G': {'H': 2}, 'F': {'H': 1, 'G': 2}, 'H': {}}
```